# Is it possible to use customised 406 page instead of default?

Tags: .htaccess

I have this on the last line in my `.htaccess`

```
# Default response
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://miranda-zhang.github.io/cloud-computing-schema/v1.0/406.html [R=406,L]
```

But when I tested, it seems to return a default Apache server page.

```
$ curl -H "Accept: anything else" http://150.203.213.249/test
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   336  100   336    0     0    336      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01  328k<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>406 Not Acceptable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Acceptable</h1>
<p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource /test could not be found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at 150.203.213.249 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

This is intended as [an entry to w3id.org](https://github.com/perma-id/w3id.org/tree/master/cocoon)

However, I can change the code to 308 to make it redirect, is this a bad practice or it doesn't matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use an `ErrorDocument` directive to render a custom page for `406` (or for `408`):

```
ErrorDocument 406 /error.html
```